# Using Concatenated Strings for

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to port a project I did in JavaScript to Java (Android), and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do certain things in Java and Android Studio that were different in JS. 
Right now I'm trying to figure out how to do this fix I had in the original JS program that took advantage of the naming convention I used to let me loop through each text label.

```
    for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
             setText("lbl" + i + j, text);
        }
    }
```

If I had label00 - label12, this could loop through all of them and set text accordingly, but I don't know how to adapt this to the setText method in Android Studio.I wanted to try something like this, but it's saying "Identifier Expected" where the findViewById command has quotes after the second period.

```
    TextView lblID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."lbl" + i + j);
    lblID.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#186cb3"));
```

Most of the UI control was based on this principal, so I need something similar if I can't get this working.

Comment: Is this `java` or `javascript`?  They are about as similar as `Austria` and `Australia`.

Comment: @JoeC Seems clear by reading the question that OP is asking about porting behaviour they wrote in JavaScript to Java.

Comment: your for loop should be `int j= 0;` not '`var j = 0;`'

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the right way for you to port from JavaScript to Android (with Java). The `findViewById()` method is used to find a certain view on the root layout of your screen using a specified `id`, it is not for setting text. You need to create a new `TextView` dynamically:

```
TextView textView = new TextView();
textView.setText("lbl" + i + j);
setTextColor(parseColor("#186cb3"));
```

then add the textView to the parent view of your layout:

```
parentView.addView(textView);
```

The `parentView` is usually the `viewGroup` on your activity layout file eg. `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`. You need to give it an `id` and get an instance of it like this:

```
RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) 
     findViewById(R.id.parent_view_id);
```

Comment: Gave you +1 for the explanation

Comment: I don't think I should need to create textViews. I've created all that I need in the layout editor, and I wanted to access and change all of them in a quick way, so I wanted to do so as I did in JS, but can't figure how.

Comment: Oh i see, if you already have them in the layout, then you should get the instance in your activity by using `findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)` like this:
`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
textView.setText(text);`